# Where can I find the Boruto series in English dub?

Tags: boruto, streaming-sites

I want to watch *Boruto*, but all I can find is *Boruto* in Japanese voice.

Are there any sites that have Boruto in English dub?

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! Take note that this site doesn't condone piracy, so we will only mention legal/official sites if they exist. Answers/comments that mention questionable sites will be removed without prompt.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, Boruto has stopped being produced in English-dub due to the ongoing [COVID-19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19) pandemic, however, English-dub episodes were still being produced while the pandemic hadn't spread as much.

Boruto has about 53 episodes in English, with the rest being in Japanese, and the sites that have Boruto in English are:

1. Hulu. Streams all 53 English Boruto episodes.
2. Amazon Prime.
3. Crunchyroll
4. Funimation.

This is about all I could find, but please note there are only 52-53 episodes in English, and was postponed due to the COVID-19 pandemic. However, most sites do offer it in Japanese with subtitles.